# Get periods of each segment for each client

Tags: mysql, sql

There are monthly periods of customer segments, I need to get the periods of each segment for each client.

Dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE segm (
    dt DATE,
    client_id VARCHAR(6),
    segment_id INT
)

INSERT INTO segm VALUES
    ('2018-01-31' ,'A11111', 2),
    ('2018-02-28' ,'A11111', 2),
    ('2018-03-31' ,'A11111', 1),
    ('2018-04-30' ,'A11111', 1),
    ('2017-11-30' ,'B22222', 1),
    ('2017-10-31' ,'B22222', 1),
    ('2017-09-30' ,'B22222', 3),
    ('2017-09-30' ,'C33333', 1),
    ('2017-10-31' ,'C33333', 1)
```

I do a SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    client_id
    , segment_id
    , FIRST_VALUE(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY dt) AS "first_value"
    , LAST_VALUE(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY dt) AS "last_value"
FROM segm
ORDER BY client_id, segment_id, "first_value", "last_value";
```

I get the result:

| client_id | segment_id | "first_value" | "last_value" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A11111 | 1 | 2018-03-31 | 2018-03-31 |
| A11111 | 1 | 2018-04-30 | 2018-04-30 |
| A11111 | 2 | 2018-01-31 | 2018-01-31 |
| A11111 | 2 | 2018-02-28 | 2018-02-28 |
| B22222 | 1 | 2017-10-31 | 2017-10-31 |
| B22222 | 1 | 2017-11-30 | 2017-11-30 |
| B22222 | 3 | 2017-09-30 | 2017-09-30 |
| C33333 | 1 | 2017-09-30 | 2017-09-30 |
| C33333 | 1 | 2017-10-31 | 2017-10-31 |

And I need:

| client_id | segment_id | "first_value" | "last_value" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A11111 | 1 | 2018-03-31 | 2018-04-30 |
| A11111 | 2 | 2018-01-31 | 2018-02-28 |
| B22222 | 1 | 2017-10-31 | 2017-11-30 |
| B22222 | 3 | 2017-09-30 | 2017-09-30 |
| C33333 | 1 | 2017-09-30 | 2017-10-31 |

How can I fix the request to get the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: You provide sample data to work with, what you have tried and desired results - an ideal question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need analytic functions, simple aggregation will give you what you need:

```
select Client_Id, Segment_Id, Min(dt) firstValue, Max(dt) LastValue
from segm
group by client_id, segment_id
order by Client_Id, Segment_Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your solution by using a `MAX` and `MIN` aggregation functions with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    client_id,
    segment_id,
    MIN(dt) AS first_value,
    MAX(dt) AS last_value
FROM 
    segm
GROUP BY 
    client_id,
    segment_id
ORDER BY 
    client_id, 
    segment_id, 
    first_value, 
    last_value
```